# Xcode Cloud: unable to open configuration settings file

Tags: xcode, react-native, xcode-cloud

I'm working with a React Native project, setting up Xcode Cloud builds.

I keep getting this error:

```
unable to open configuration settings file
Pods-XXX.debug.xcconfig:1
```

[image: Xcode Cloud Screenshot]

The files in my workspace look like the following:

```
|-- XXX
|-- Pods
|.  -- Podfile
|.  -- Targets Support Files
|.     -- Pods-XXX
|.        -- Pods-XXX.debug
```

Comment: Check out this link, it seemed to work for me: https://zach.codes/xcode-cloud-react-native-setup/

Answer (score 36):

Guess what? XCode is garbage but doc can help us here.

This what I'm using to smoothly build my workflow. I'l share exact bash scripts here.

Why it's failing?

1. First open logs on your workflow window side bar.
2. Check if you're installing necessary dependencies before running archive process. You're using virtual machine so any dependencies like cocoapods or yarn aren't installed by default there.

**If you haven't read and skipped to the SOLUTION:**

Here is the steps:

1. Create `ci_scripts` folder inside ios folder.
2. Create 3 files inside `ci_scripts` folder:

   1. `ci_post_clone.sh`
   2. `ci_post_xcodebuild.sh`
   3. `ci_pre_xcodebuild.sh`
3. Inside your `ci_post_clone.sh` file add this:

   ```
    #!/bin/zsh

    # fail if any command fails

    echo " Stage: Post-clone is activated .... "

    set -e
    # debug log
    set -x

    # Install dependencies using Homebrew. This is MUST! Do not delete.
    brew install node yarn cocoapods fastlane

    # Install yarn and pods dependencies.
    # If you're using Flutter or Swift 
    # just install pods by "pod install" command 
    ls && cd .. && yarn && pod install

    echo " Stage: Post-clone is done .... "

    exit 0
   ```
4. Inside your `ci_pre_xcodebuild.sh` file add this:

   ```
    #!/bin/zsh

    echo " Stage: PRE-Xcode Build is activated .... "

    # You can add additional scripts here...

    echo " Stage: PRE-Xcode Build is DONE .... "

    exit 0
   ```
5. Inside your `ci_post_xcodebuild.sh` file add this:

   ```
    #!/bin/zsh

    echo " Stage: POST-Xcode Build is activated .... "

    # You can add additional scripts here...

    echo " Stage: POST-Xcode Build is DONE .... "

    exit 0
   ```

Comment: I'm working on the build now. Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Glad if it helped. DM me, if you're facing problems.

Comment: I tried this but didn't fix the error. I am using xcode 14.1 & react native 0.70.6.

Comment: @A.A., what error are you getting there?

Comment: @BEKROZ, this the error I am receiving "unable to open configuration settings file" while creating a local build on a simulator.

Comment: I fixed this by increasing min deployment target to 13.

Comment: @A.A. Make sure your ci_scripts are pushed in your remote code repository and triggers are in place on a specific branch.

Comment: i got errors saying it was trying to tun these in MacOs zsh on xcode cloud. Any idea?

"The ci_pre_xcodebuild.sh is not executable and was run using zsh (default shell on macOS). To make sure your script runs correctly, make the file executable using `chmod +x` and add an appropriate shebang line."

Comment: What iOS folder?

Comment: Thanks, but i get the same error  ‍

Comment: @jgvb means on root...

Answer (score 19):

In my case I run `pod install` inside /ios folder and worked

Comment: this could be because you have the `./ios` folder in your version control. The issue above probably appears on Prebuild processes, where you expect to build the iOS project from scratch with expo

Comment: this is my issue, I clone a React Native project, run ios workshop in Xcode, you need go to the folder with Podfile & Podfile.lock, run pod install

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was about cocoapods. I removed old versions,installed from ground and linked, problem solved :)

```
brew uninstall --cask cocoapods

brew install cocoapods

brew link --overwrite cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue recently, there is now a default workflow for xcode cloud that performs the post clone step that was provided by @BEK ROZ

I also had the same issue locally when building a VueJS app with Ionic/Capacitor

Before now my knowledge of iOS builds is precisely zero, so excuse innocence, but I found the issues were relating to the *xcconfig files. Every capacitor module that you install with npm will have it's own xcconfig file for debug and release - Stored in:

```
ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/{{ Module Name }}/{{ Module Name }}.debug.xcconfig

ios/App/Pods/Target Support Files/{{ Module Name }}/{{ Module Name }}.release.xcconfig
```

I've only installed two plugins, so I uninstalled one of them, which was cordova-plugin-screen-orientation, synced and then archived (steps below) and this time it passed.

```
# Remove a capacitor module with npm e.g. cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm uninstall cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

# Sync the iOS plugins to remove the plugin from your Podfile (ios/App/Podfile)
npx cap sync ios
```

So I'd recommend going through all of the plugins you've installed and see if any of them are playing up. Then go back to xcode, run "Product -> Archive" from the menus to start a new build or push your changes and let xcode cloud do the heavy lifting for you.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for providing additional solution. 

Answer (score -1):

This can happen when you merge project.pbxproj with changes that are not in your branch. The solution is:

- To undo the merge commit.
- Remove this file from the commit.
- Commit again.

In some cases, you will need more specific manipulations like @BEK ROZ mentioned before.